# Using personally licensed software on a corporate PC

Tags: licensing, corporate-law, natural-person

Let's say I have a personal license for a product as Visual Studio or TOAD or anything else: am I able to **legally** use it on a corporate computer?

What about products, that are intended for free use in small groups of developers only (Community/Indie editions)?

Comment: It would depend wholly on the license terms. If you can tell us the license type it would help us answer.

Comment: @Terry it might also depend on company policy.

Comment: @phoog: That would be a workplace related question, not a legal question. But if we change "can I do this legally" to "can I get into trouble", which is what most people care about, then absolutely, you can get into trouble with your company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the license. For example if you purchase an application on Apple's App Store, you have free choices: 1. Private use on several computers that you own and control. 2. Professional use on any number of computers that are exclusively used by you. 3. Professional use on one single computer that is used by any number of users. Other companies probably have similar licenses.

So if that was your software license, you could install the software on any number of company computers that are used only by you and use it professionally, but you couldn't then use it on a personal computer as well. And independent of the software license, your company might not agree with this. For example, depending on the laws in place it might be illegal for a company to let employees pay for such software out of their own pocket.